# Change image in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to adapt a template for my website. I'm no CSS guru, but I'm trying to find a way to change images on a timer. Problem is, the template is CSS and I don't know how to make a very simple slideshow. I'd just like to change the image every 5 seconds or so.

Here's what I have in the html file:

```
<div id="mainPicture">
  <div class="picture">
    <div id="headerTitle">Header Text</div>
     <div id="headerSubtext">Header Subtext</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS stuff:

```
#mainPicture
{
clear:both;
width:670px;
height:345px;
background-color:#160306;
}

#mainPicture .picture
{
position:relative;
width:650px;
height:325px;
top:10px;
margin-left:10px;
background-image:url(LOGO2.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Any way to change the image url every few seconds to a different file?

Comment: How do you have these urls for all these different images stored? Is it in an array in JavaScript? Do you call a webService to get the 'next' image?

Comment: Try googling for "jquery image slideshow"

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible with just CSS. you need to leverage some sort of JavaScript to get this done as you said after an Interval of 5 seconds. You might want to use `setTimeout()` function. I had writted a script to change the background color of the page using JavaSCript. You might want to leverage this to change the image instead of the background color:

Here is the link:

http://codeforbrowser.com/blog/changing-background-color-using-javascript-and-jquery/

And below is the DEMO:

http://jsfiddle.net/refhat/gJWFR/1/

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest looking into some of the CSS3 properties, if it has to be strictly CSS. Otherwise I would look into Jquery.

Here is a link to CSS3
http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp